# ¿De dónde viene llamar "abuelito" al diente de león?

Tags: etimología, diferencias-regionales, españa, plantas

En el chat que tenemos para tratar los juegos de [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf): [Translation Golf!](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41881995#41881995) hemos hablado del *diente de león* y al preguntar a @walen si los llamaban **abuelitos** por sus tierras me ha dicho que jamás ha oído eso.

No he encontrado muchas referencias pero en algunos blogs sí se menciona ese nombre. en uno de esos blogs aparecen varios nombres uno de ellos «meacamas» que también reconozco, a la flor le llamamos *meacamas* y a la bola que forman las semillas *abuelito*. (Soy del País Vasco.)

> Al ser una planta tan omnipresente, los nombres comunes son tantos
> como los pueblos que la conocen, aludiendo a una u otra de sus muchas
> propiedades atribuidas.(...) o a la característica bola blanca de
> vilanos de su fruto ("Panaderos", "Abuelos").
>
> <sub>Fuente: http://javibichos.blogspot.com.es/2013/09/diente-de-leon.html</sub>

¿Por qué se le llama «abuelito» y dónde? ¿Qué otros nombres tiene el diente de león en vuestras regiones?

Comment: Cuando yo era chico acá los llamábamos *panaderos*.

Comment: @pablodf76 - Sería mejor aclarar dónde es "acá" para los que no te conozcan todavía, por favor.

Comment: @aparente001 No aclaré (Argentina) porque no pensaba que sirviera mucho como respuesta. ¿Cuál es la política para respuestas que piden armar listas?

Comment: @pablodf76 Lo que me interesaba en realidad era saber porque se les llama abuelito aunque al ver que era algo regional añadí la segunda pregunta para ver cómo de extendida estaba esa denominación y si otros nombres podrían ser similares o me daban alguna pista

Comment: ¿Será por la barba blanca de un abuelito?

Comment: @MauricioMartinez podría ser, o por el pelo blanco. ¿Y lo de panadero que comenta Pablo quizá venga porque están llenos de harina siempre? Me gusta esa teoría.

Comment: En Chile le decimos "carta" (me imagino que porque viaja).

Answer (score 1):

Curiosamente el DLE en una versión más antigua recogía esa entrada ([Diccionario de la lengua española (2001)](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/)).

> **abuelo, la.**
>
> 5. m. vulg. Ál. Vilano del fruto de ciertas plantas, especialmente si es grande y de filamentos suaves.

Y la definición de vilano:
[**vilano**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bocQ93E)

> 1. m. Apéndice de pelos o filamentos que corona el fruto de muchas plantas compuestas y le sirve para ser transportado por el aire.

Y por lo que se puede ver allí, era algo específico de [Álava](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81lava). Habría que ver por qué se quitó esa entrada de las ediciones más nuevas.

Ahora, otro de los significados de abuelo, que si se conserva en el nuevo DLE es el [siguiente](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0DKKo2d):

> 4. m. Cada uno de los mechoncitos que quedan sueltos en la nuca cuando se atiranta el cabello hacia arriba. U. m. en pl.

Mi teoría es que estos "mechoncitos" o pelusas que quedarían en el cuello al recoger el cabello se asemejan a las [cipsela](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipsela) (pelitos) del diente de león.

Comment: Interesante, aunque eso no explica de donde viene la palabra está claro que su uso era significativo, al menos en una zona, si aparecía en el diccionario y  lo de los pelillos de la nuca puede que sea una buena pista también

Answer (score 0):

Hace poco estuve tambien interesado en el significado y la historia de esta peculiar planta porque me quería hacer un tatuaje relacionado. Por lo visto en cada región donde nace se llama de una forma distinta. Te dejo un enlace de los que estuve leyendo donde hablan un poco más sobre su significado aunque tampoco aclaran de donde provienen esas palabras.
https://minitatuajes.com/tattoo/diente-leon/

Comment: Bienvenido manuteris. Por favor pasate por el boton de ayuda que hay arriba a la derecha. En la sección como hacer una buena respuesta. Las respuestas que solo se refieren a un enlace no son bienvenidas ya que el enlace puede desaparecer en cualquier momento. Debes copiar aquí las partes relevantes dejando el enlace solo como una referencia. https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer